# Object cannot be converted to Entry<String,Integer>

Tags: java, hashmap

This error appears when i try to loop my hashmap, and i have no idea why.

**Object cannot be converted to Entry**

Into package1:

```
protected static final Map<String, Integer> distanceLabels = new HashMap<>();
```

Into the package im having the error:

```
Map distanceLabels = package1.distanceLabels;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : distanceLabels.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't see, you are removing an item from map

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply replace this:

```
Map distanceLabels = package1.distanceLabels;
```

With this

```
Map<String, Integer> distanceLabels = package1.distanceLabels;
```

Indeed if you don't specify any *parameterized types* to the declaration of your map, the compiler cannot know the *parameterized types* of the `entries` which is the reason why he raises an error since you expect `entries` of specific types.

You need to remain consistent in both places such that you have actually 2 ways to fix it, you cannot do something in between as you did above:

1. You can specify explicitly the *parametrized types* in both places like proposed above which is clearly the best approach
2. You can create a *raw type* of `Map` as you did (no parameterized types defined) and create a *raw type* of `Map.Entry` but you will then have to explicitly cast your `key` and your `value` to the expected types.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the map `Map<String, Integer>` like this:

```
  Map<String, Integer> distanceLabels = package1.distanceLabels;
 for(Entry<String, Integer> entry : distanceLabels.entrySet()) {
   String key = entry.getKey();
   Object value = entry.getValue();

  }
```